# Radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 4^{{(-1)}^n n} z^{2n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Find Radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 4^{{(-1)}^n n} z^{2n}$

I tried root test here so we have $|z|^2 \lim_{n\to \infty} 4^{{(-1)}^n} $ should be <1 to find out |z|. But I am having problem solving this limit and further proceeding.

Comment: It is enough to look at the $\limsup$ instead of the $\lim$.

Comment: How? I have never computed limsup, I always use root test or ratio test to find radius of convergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate the even and odd terms, and calculate the radii of convergence for both series.

Comment: So do we have $|z|<1/2 $when n is even $\quad |z|<2$ when n is odd. Then when take min(1/2,2) to be radius of convergence?

Comment: @ketan Exactly.  Be warned that this step requires justification; it is possible to add two series with the same radius of convergence and have the radius of convergence change, but I believe this is impossible when the radii are different.

Comment: @ketan Or maybe it's fine when the radii are the same.  In any case, this answer is really just a restatement of the lim sup idea, and it's a good exercise to examine why this is.

Answer (score 1):

It is [the very same root test you know](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence#Theoretical_radius) but formulated with $\limsup$ instead of $\lim$. The limit doesn't always exist, but with the $\limsup$ does give you a value in $[0,\infty]$

The $\limsup$ is the supremum of the limits of all convergent subsequences.

For $4^{(-1)^n}$ there are two possible limits of convergent subsequences: $4$ and $4^{-1}$.